# How to allow access to DB of phpMyAdmin from outside?

Tags: java, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have allowed access to phpMyAdmin on first PC. I can open phpMyAdmin by opening in browser `http://192.168.100.10:8080/phpmyadmin` on another PC in local LAN. And also I can open via browser DB in phpMyAdmin on another PC

But I can't create connection to the DB via java code:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// Setup the connection with the DB
Properties info = new Properties();
info.put("characterEncoding", "UTF-8");
info.put("user", "root");
info.put("password", "");
info.put("autoReconnect", "true");
info.put("useSSL", "false");
info.put("failOverReadOnly", "false");
info.put("maxReconnects", "10");
info.put("connectTimeout", "2000");

DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(10);
mConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.10:8080/flats_flx", info
);//here it's stuck 

mStatement = mConnection.createStatement();
```

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/27700425/2425851 I found that I need to "Allow Network Access to MySQL"
**How to do that in phpMyAdmin?**

Comment: `Class.forName` isn't doing anything in your code. Your `DriverManager` handles that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this way check your port number i think MySql is `3306`:

```
public class CreateConnection {
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String DB_username = "username";
    String DB_password = "password";
    String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.100.10:3306/flats_flx";

    public Connection getConnection() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_username, DB_password);
            System.out.println(con);
            return con;

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Exception " + e);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right , a lot of thanks. You have saved my salary))

Comment: you are welcom @NickUnuchek

Answer (score 2):

```
Class.forName(driver);
java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ip_of_host_server:3306/Database_name", DB_username, DB_password);
```

Comment: `jdbc:mysql://ip_of_host_server:3306/Database_name` should be a String and not like you do now `"jdbc:mysql://ip_of_host_server:3306/Database_name"`

Comment: Yes ! , Thanks @YCF_L for Correction .